# Decoupling code with dynamic data and multiple constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, decoupling

I am creating a complex java service which gets a `Connection` and a `Document` as input. This `Connection` is used to instantiate an `ObjectDAO` and `Configuration` objects which are then used by other classes to get relevant data. Sample code:

```
public class MyService{

    public Document solve(Connection conn, Document input, Document input2){
        OwnConfiguration config = new OwnConfiguration(conn);
        ObjectDAO oDAO = new ObjectDAO(conn);
        List<String> entityList = oDAO.getList();
        FirstDataCruncher fCruncher = new FirstDataCruncher(oDAO, config, input);
        Map<String, Map<String, String> > usefulData = fCruncher.getData();
        Map<String, String> usefulData2 = fCruncher.getMoreData();
        //Basically the crunchers get data from DB, store them in state variables which are used by other objects as and when needed.

        SecondDataCruncher sCruncher = new SecondDataCruncher(oDAO, config, input2, usefulData2);
        Map<String, String> usefulData3 = sCruncher.getData();

        FinalSolver fSolver = new FinalSolver(usefulData1..2.3);
        for(String i : entityList){
            fSolver.finishThis(i, oDAO);
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to reduce the coupling between various classes but have been unable to come up with any good logic. DI frameworks such as `Spring` are good when you can dealing with static/available before runtime data, but what is a good approach for such a situation?

I can create all these classes without arguments and inject them into each other (passing `Connection`, `inputxml` and other args via setters) but that seems like a pretty poor solution too, since I will have multiple setter lines per class before running any logic.

How should I tackle this scenario?

Comment: Some [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) maybe

Comment: But that wouldn't help me reduce coupling between the lower classes would it? Eg: `FinalSolver` creates a couple more classes `Helper1`, `Helper2`. Should I pass them via `MyService` itself? What about classes created by `Helper1` itself? Sorry if I am over-complicating things a bit, but I am thinking I need some kind of DI too (no idea how to do that though)

Comment: Not everything needs to be under springs control, just because you can. I would however strive for not passing `Connection` objects around (assuming that that is a `javax.sql.Connection`, that generally isn't a good idea. However without knowing that information or seeing the implementation of for instance `OwnConfiguration` and the other objects it is hard to determine.

Comment: So actually the `Connection` is taken from a `connection pool`. I am passing around this pool and getting the connection wherever needed. This is a legacy application and hence my hands are tied regarding the input. How would you recommend I should handle the interior dependencies then? I am finding it hard to test the application because of these interior classes and thus, was trying to figure out ways to decouple things